# Git clone from Windows to Windows cannot find the repository

Tags: windows, ssh, git

`git clone gituser@<server>:myRepo.git` doesn't work, fails with the error message:

`fatal: ''myRepo.git'' does not appear to be a git repository`

Background:

We have a Windows 7 machine set up with Git Bash and Bitvise WinSSHd (on `C:`). The SSH server is set up to use `<git dir>/bin/sh.exe --login` as the shell, with the home directory set to `/a/`. I can SSH onto the server just fine, and it drops me into the Git Bash shell as expected, starting in the `/a/` directory.

I have a bare repository at `/a/myRepo.git` (on the `A:` disk) which does everything it should, as long as we're doing it locally. I can `git clone /a/myRepo.git`, work on it, push and pull, no problems as long as it's local (or "local" over SSH). Furthermore, we set up the A: disk as a shared folder, and I can clone, push, and pull from a local network machine using `\\<server>\myRepo.git`.

When I try to clone remotely, however, I cannot figure out what combination of options will allow it to work: The obvious clone string doesn't work, putting an absolute pathname in either *nix-converted format (`/a/myRepo.git` and `A:/myRepo.git`) or Windows format (`A:\\myRepo.git`) fails with the same error, the permissions on the directory are set up to allow all users, and I've set `git config core.sharedRepository all` on the serving machine as well.

I had a suspicion of Git Bash's remapping of Windows drive letters into `/<letter>` format, but I tried creating another bare repository on C: and it gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read about supported by Git protocols and format of URLs
2. Use **correct, unambiguously interpreted** URL for the repository: while you use SSH and URLS *seems* as SSH, it resembles more format of SCP. I.e - starting point in path part isn't $HOME, but root of your ssh-server

I'll expect `ssh://gituser@<server>/~/myRepo.git` have to work (formally, besides some possible additional unrelated to ssh problems)

Comment: The full string, including protocol and path name didn't work. Adding the protocol interprets things between : and / as a port.

Comment: @harbichidian - mea culpa, URL corrrected. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS used as reference

Comment: Tried `.../~/myRepo.git`, `.../a/myRepo.git`, and `.../myRepo.git`. None worked, all returned the same error with the host and initial slash stripped in the message (''~/myRepo.git'' does not appear...).